# "Any public static members of XmlDocument are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe" : yes, but

Tags: c#, thread-safety, xmldocument, xmlnodelist

I see in the [`XmlDocument` class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN that

> Any public static ( Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Same thing for the `XmlNodeList` class.

I am using those classes in the following context. Inside a `Parallel.Foreach` I do :

```
X MyX = new X();
string XMLstring = MyX.GetXML(ID, true);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(XMLstring);
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("blah/secondblah");
```

where `X` is defined in a library the IT's are providing to me and where `ID` is an `int` (roughly on which I loop).

This has been tested thoroughly in a non parallel context, the `string`s produced by `GetXML` are indeed correct, the corresponding `XmlDocument` as well, and "parsing" it via `XmlNodeList` provides the expected results.

Now, it this parallel context and assuming that `X` and `GetXML` are indeed thread-safe, does the fact that I `new` an `XmlDocument` in every loop ensure thread-safety or not ? I mean, how can I know that the `string` member (first of all is there such a string ? as I don't see any `string` property in the document) of `XmlDocument` receiving the `LoadXml` is `static` or not ?

I suppose I don't really understand the bit of MSDN documentation I am quoting above ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation means that any methods that are static (which would look like `XmlDocument.MethodCall` are thread-safe. That isn't relevant to you - you aren't calling any of those. *Other methods (e.g. against `doc`) are not static - so they are not guaranteed to be thread-safe.*

Your code will be 100% fine, as long as `doc` (and `nodeList` and other 'non thread-safe' variables) are used solely within the context of a single thread.

So if you populated `doc` **before** the Parallel.ForEach and then used `doc` **inside** the Parallel.ForEach - that won't work.

But if you populate and used `doc` **inside** the Parallel.ForEach you will be fine (since each thread will get its 'own doc'- thus thread-safety won't be an issue).

To be 100% sure, you'd need to post the entire method (including the Parallel.ForEach call) for us to have a look at.

Comment: I confirm that `doc` (and `nodeList` and other 'non thread-safe' variables) are used solely within the context of a single thread. About the document : I only see "members" mentionned, not "methods". I am fairly new to `C#`, so have missed some vocabulary point or ?

Comment: "Members" includes methods (code) and properties (data).

Comment: In the context of this question, members and methods are equivalent. Apologies for changing the terminology on you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is thread safe. You are not sharing anything between threads. I have used similar XmlDocument code in large multi-threaded applications without problems. In theory there could be private static data in XmlDocument that we don't know about which is not thread safe, but my experience is that this is not the case. I think the MSDN documentation is implying that Microsoft have made sure that any static stuff which may be shared across threads, is in fact thread safe.

Comment: Yes, "there could be private static data in XmlDocument that we don't know about which is not thread safe" was exactly my point.

Comment: As @mjwills answered before you I will accept his answer, but yours reassuares me ! Thx a lot.