# Are XmlNode Operations "By Reference"? C#

Tags: c#, xml

This code works but I want to understand why I don't have the pass the modified `XmlDocument` back to the caller - a code review I guess ;). I assume that these operations within `XmlNode` are using "by Ref" internally to operate on the document. I can see that working but I just want to make sure I understand this correctly. I have not found any documentation that addresses this specifically - probably because it is so obvious. So help me out here fellow devs. This is all happening by Ref and I don't have to worry about passing the modified `XmlDocument` back to the caller correct? Also, is this thread safe? I am using this code as part of a service app.

```
public void AddNewElement(XmlDocument doc, string elementName)
{
    XmlNode selectedNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//" + elementName);
    if (selectedNode == null)
    {
        var childNodes = doc.LastChild.LastChild.ChildNodes;
        XmlNode appendNode = childNodes.Item(childNodes.Count - 1);
        XmlNode newNode = appendNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement(elementName));
        newNode.InnerText = str64;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quite simply, `XmlDocument` is a *reference type.*  Modifying it in place is a perfectly feasible operation.

Comment: Is it your expectation that `AddNewElement` will be operating on the same doc in *two different threads?*

Comment: Regarding [thread-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44367866/1997232).

Comment: [Documentation about passing reference types and how you can modify it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters)

Comment: You might want to read Jon Skeet's (quite old, but it's not wrong) primer on [parameter passing](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html)

Comment: I understand what Reference Types are and passing by ref etc. My question was specifically about XMLNode and there does not appear to be any documentation to verify what we all know by experience.